# Bootstrap 4, make list-group scrollable, in a row, with flexbox, with or without body scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm using **Bootstrap 4** (now I'm on alpha-6).

I have this situation:

```
<body>

  <!-- HERE I HAVE one div automatically generated with randomly ID and class -->

  <div class="bigone">

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="header">
        My header
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="mybar">
      Nav bar
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                Card Header
              </div>
              <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><b>FIRST LINK</b></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>                    
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</a>

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action disabled"><b>LAST LINK</b></a>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                Card Footer
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6">
            <h1>FIRST LINE</h1> So many words, so many words. So many words, so many words. So many words, so many words.
            <br> So many words, so many words. So many words, so many words. So many words, so many words.
            <br> So many words, so many words. So many words, so many words. So many words, so many words.
            <br>
            <h1>LAST LINE</h1>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- HERE THAT DIV CLOSED -->

</body>
```

This is the **css**:

```
.bigone {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

There is a **DEMO on plnkr**: https://plnkr.co/edit/Q9PQIj8uDFY80bxJGks3

I need footer to be on bottom when the page content is empty, for this reason I'm using: `.bigone { height: 100vh; }` and Bootstrap Flexbox align utilities like: `<div class="bigone d-flex flex-column">`

Now I need the `list-group` in `card` and the `col-6` with "so many words" to be scrollable, so to have an height for both max to the bottom where the footer is.

In a nutshell: **BODY must not have the scroll bar**.

My header and footer height are not fixed, they change.

**How to?** I'm not a flexbox expert.

I don't need IE, just Chrome.

**IMPORTANT**:

I can't make my card height fixed with something like this:

```
height: calc(100vh - header.height - footer.height - etc...);
```

because my header, footer, etc. heights change dynamically.

**Picture of the problem**:

[image: WHAT I NEED]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common), the setting `flex: 1` (on the `.main` element) is equivalent to `flex: 1 1 0`, shorthand for:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

However, for some reason, `flex: 1` is not working as expected in your code. (I'm only checking in Chrome, per your question).

However, if you give `.main` the full shorthand – and make it a flex container and add `overflow` – your layout appears to work.

```
.main {
    flex: 1 1 0; /* flex: 1, which you had before, is equivalent but doesn't work */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[**revised plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/arhN6vwRaq3rOKwBwcQ3?p=preview)

Reference:

- [7.1.1. Basic Values of `flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)

---

**EDIT** (based on changes to the question)

My answer above removes scrollbars from the `body` and provides a vertical scrollbar for the `.main` section.

To make vertical scroll bars available for each column in the `.main` section,  make this adjustment:

```
.main {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    display: flex;
}
.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
}
.col-6 {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[**revised plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/gMbgxvUqHNDsQVe4P7ny?p=preview)

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear enough. I need the `card` in `col-6` to be scrollable, without using `height: calc(100vh - [header and footer height])`. How to do that? You answer for what is? It doesn't change scrollable feature of the two `col-6` to my own plnkr.

Comment: My demo is different than yours. The scrollbar works as you request. And there is no `height` or `calc`.

Comment: Ok, dear @Michael_B, I misunderstood your answer, but still it isn't what I need. I need to show `Footer` at bottom, but ONLY when both `col-6` columns have scrollbar and their height is (100% of the page minus height of header, navbar and footer). All this dinamically, because my header and footer height changes and so I can't use `calc()`. This is my question. I updated plnkr. I will update my question with screenshots.

Comment: In your question you say: *I need footer to be on bottom even if the page content is empty*.

Comment: Yes, but not when there is content. I updated question. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, we almost are... I updated my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Q9PQIj8uDFY80bxJGks3: I need scroll on `list-group`, not `col-6`. How to?

Comment: Ok, really last doubt: I updated my plunker with your css translated in Bootstrap utility (it's the same and it works good!), but now there is a little problem: my Angular project creates some divs with randomly classes and IDs every time, in my plunker I called it `somethingRandomlyEveryTime`. If I not put the class `d-flex` or the same css `display: flex` on every div who contains my cards it doesn't works. This is the real problem of my tests.

Comment: That sounds like an Angular issue. This question was about CSS. You may want to post another question focusing on Angular.

Comment: Yes, but the css question is: is it really necessary `display: flex` on every upper divs?

Comment: When you make an element a flex container (`display: flex` or `inline-flex`) it automatically gives the children full height (`align-items: stretch`). That's the reason: you get dynamic full height; no `calc` or `height` necessary.

Comment: Ok, I understand. This problem is mine, but only now I realized that enlarging the window columns no longer complies with the responsiveness. Look at it: https://run.plnkr.co/iUqgmpIMvFUEaerk/, this is the plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Awoof7KfACHXlPpQYNLo

Comment: Your demo doesn't have any of the code from my answers. You're missing the `overflow-y`, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately also in your plnkr there is the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/gMbgxvUqHNDsQVe4P7ny (big page: https://run.plnkr.co/lLz9uWiw7SDsfxTO/) the only difference is your columns are centered.

Comment: You're on the wrong plunkr. My answer works in both the small and large screen: https://run.plnkr.co/HtUpdYmIACNEDkHI/

Comment: At link you posted now (https://run.plnkr.co/HtUpdYmIACNEDkHI) I see the two columns centered, even if they are `col-6`. This is the problem. Enlarge the window, please.

Comment: We're not seeing the same thing. My link worked when I sent it to you. When you sent it back it doesn't. Now it doesn't work at all (Page Not Found). Something strange going on.

Comment: Make sure the code from my revised answer is included in your layout. It works. Maybe try in another IDE (like jsfiddle.net or codepen.io).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133036/discussion-between-john-sam-and-michael-b).

Comment: if I have a long page and I don't need the footer in front, how can I put the scroll in bottom like no flexbox? In this fork (https://plnkr.co/edit/DdrXhlxWPY015OLmZTm6) when I scroll the page the footer remains there.

Comment: Works fine on Edge.

Comment: For Chrome try `.main { flex: 1 1 auto }` instead of `flex: 1 1 0`.

Comment: It doesn't work on Chrome because the scroll in page where I need to scroll doesn't work anymore, just disappear.

Comment: Dear Michael_b, I opened this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175481/different-behaviour-of-flexbox-with-overflow-y-scroll-on-safari-firefox-and-e. Why this behavior?

Comment: @Michael_B would you be willing to make the solution a little more general for folks being directed here by google? I have two bootstrap columns, I'd like them both to scroll independently and occupy the full vertical space.. what do I do?

Comment: @AlexLenail, consider posting a new question, with all your details and requirements. That may bring in answers more suitable to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I have

```
<div class="fixed-top collapse show wrapper">
 <ul class="list-group bg-white menu">
 </ul>
</div>
```

I fixed it by

```
.wrapper {
    margin-top: 48px; /* place it under navbar */
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 48px; /* compensate margin top */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Created a new Plunker to showcase what you're looking for.](https://plnkr.co/edit/cxLJ1Yry5O8V1lN87mQ3?p=preview)

To keep the footer on the bottom use [Bootstrap Flexbox Auto Margins](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#auto-margins).

If you want to keep your main content within the initial viewport height, use the `flex-grow:1` property with `overflow-y:scroll`. Its height will adopt responsively based on the space the other elements use.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I need all this in `list-group` of the `card` component. Not the simple header, main and footer, unfortunately.